# How do I stop overflow in a textarea element completely?

Tags: html, css

For a `<textarea>`, in CSS, I set `overflow: hidden`.

But it still scrolls the text up, even though its hidden and has no scroll bar.

I want the user to not be able to add more content once they reach the bottom of the `<textarea>`.

How do I do that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: You want to limit the text to be entered: [check this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47941/How-to-limit-the-number-of-lines-and-characters-in)

Comment: maxlength almost works, except the user can keep pushing the [enter]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding:

Example :- http://jsfiddle.net/8fv6e/3/

```
        #textarea { height: 100px; 
            max-height: 100px; }
```

Comment: Thanks.  But that did not change anything.  I already have a height and adding the max-height made no difference.

Comment: I add link of example please check

Comment: That example overflows.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's difficult to do that but you can control it

there are several ways :

1. use cols and rows for sizing the "textarea"

   ```
    <textarea  cols="73" rows="12">.....</textarea>
   ```
2. give it fixed size by styling it using

   ```
       textarea {resize: none;}
   ```
3. give max-height & min-height the same value

and in all previous cases use

```
 overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it is try adding `overflow: hidden; height: 100px;` and it world stop it from scrolling. Here is the link you can check out here https://codepen.io/ravitaneja/pen/RQYrGV